# ant sonar merge multiple reports into one

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I am using ant sonar on my project. There are multiple modules in my project, is it possible to merge the reports of all the projects into one so that it appears as a single project on Sonar Qube console?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this, but it requires purchase of the commercial [views plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/).